# Automatic DB creation with MongoDB in Kubernetes or OpenShift

Tags: scripting, mongodb, kubernetes, openshift-origin

I have a MongoDB cluster in Kubernetes, it's pushed to Kube with a StatefulSet type of deployment.

That part work's good, I can even create 1 DB with variables starting with that...

My question is, how do I create more than 1 DB within Mongo at first run time?

Let's say I have 5 DB to create with their respective user/pass

- db-foo
- db-bar
- db-test
- db-lotr
- db-thedb

How can I make sure these are initiated/created at first deploy time?
Do I just create a SHELL script within mongodb/pre-init/ and rebuild my Mongo with my scripts in there?

Do I use another set of variables numbered?

I am confused. Please help me.

Comment: Why isn't your application doing its own database migrations?

Comment: It is not about migration, it is about initiating the DB at first container install. I can do it via variables, but I can only do 1 DB... I need to create more than DB in my case...

Comment: Database migrations do that too.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Can you elaborate ?

Comment: What is it you want elaborated?